# XML format error nunjucks template rendering

Tags: javascript, templates, nunjucks

I'm getting the following console error when rendering nunjucks templte that extends another:

```
Erro no processamento de XML: formatação incorreta Posição: http://localhost/prj/js/templates/template.tpl?s=1517784777473 Número da linha 1, coluna 1:
```

this roughly translates to:

```
XML processing error: incorrect formatting Position: http://localhost/prj/js/templates/template.tpl?s=1517784777473 Line number  1, column 1:
```

(I couldn't find the error directly in it's english original form, that's why I translated it)

Yet the template is rendered correctly.

The template that I'm rendering is this:

```
{% extends "base/header.tpl" %}
{% block main %}
<div id="container">
    <h1>Prj</h1>
    <div id='element'>
        whatever
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

this is header.tpl:

```
<div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

this is nunjucks configuration:

```
nunjucks.configure('js/templates', { autoescape: true, trimBlocks: true, lstripBlocks: true });
```

and this is how the rendering is done:

```
var renderization = nunjucks.render("main.tpl", {});
$("#root").append(renderization);
```

Anyone knows why I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this error is generated by the browser. When the nunjucks requests a next template from the server, the response comes marked as XML. Browser try process it and throw error (because is a not XML). You can simple check it: open browser console (F12) and go to network tab.

You must set mime-type as `text/html` for nunjucks templates on http-server side.